# Mongo validation fails when connecting to a DB on another computer in lan network

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, authentication

So I have this API app running on my machine, and a MongoServer running on another computer in the same local network. 
I have figured that this has to have something to do with the fact that the mongoserver is on another host, because the same Models and Schemas work fine when app is running on same host as server.
I can successfully make GET requests, however when I try to make a POST request my app crashes saying that my schema validation failed.

Do I need to make any extra authentication for that? If yes, how do I go about that?

Comment: did you check if you have a firewall that is blocking the mongodb port?

Comment: Yes, I can successfully connect to that host on 27017 port (which is the same port which I connect to the db with)

Comment: I just checked with telnet btw.